# Determining kind of facebook app

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

https://apps.facebook.com/horoscopes/?fb_source=search

Can anyone tell me what kind of facebook app it is? canvas or something else?

I would want to create an app in php but have no clue where to start from. Can i create a test app and start the process? please help.

I have tried creating an app but that needs to be approved before even starting the development and showing us as a page on facebook app

Comment: I suggest just finding an sdk and tutorial first on google.

Comment: I have found lot of tutorials there are mainly 4 sdks but i would want to find out first determining what kind of app can give me similar look and feel as mentioned above.Once done then i can easily google up the sdk apis.

Comment: Yes it is a canvas app and you can read about how to create one at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/canvas

Answer (score 0):

Any app with an address of `apps.facebook.com/*` is the Canvas link to the App, which means this app has a canvas page at the minimum. It may also have a website and mobile app associated with it, but that's harder to determine.

You should so some research before trying to create an app. You do not need to get any sort of approval to develop an application, even if you use excessive permissions. However, you will need to get your app approved for any extra permissions prior to launching to end-users.

You should visit the [Facebook Developer website](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/) and pick a SDK you're comfortable with. I would recommend using the JavaScript one to get started, but the choice is yours. Then you should follow the starter guide to creating your first app. Everything you need to create an app is discoverable through Google, and I have a [few handy tutorials](https://www.webniraj.com/tag/facebook/) on my site for using the PHP and JavaScript SDKs.